# Nested function call in onClick not firing

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari

I have an application written in javascript with React. When clicking a button in Safari on iOS, the onClick executes the function specified in its body, but that function takes another function as a callback and that callback function doesn't get fired.

If I just send the callback without an anonymous function, it works. But if I use an anonymous function to call the callback, it doesn't work.

The code below is an excerpt from the render()-method of the React class.

This doesn't work in Safari on iOS(but works just fine in Chrome on iOS):

```
<button className="button-top-level" data-selenium-id="preview"
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.saveApplicationFunction(null, () => this.refs.downloadButton.click(););
          }} type="button"><i className="material-icons">picture_as_pdf</i>Download a <span className="mobile-hide">copy of your </span>application</button>
```

This works in Safari on iOS and Chrome on iOS:

```
<button className="button-top-level" data-selenium-id="preview"
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.saveApplicationFunction(null, this.refs.downloadButton.click());
          }} type="button"><i className="material-icons">picture_as_pdf</i>Download a <span className="mobile-hide">copy of your </span>application</button>
```

I don't get any errors when it fails, it just doesn't fire the callback. I understand that I can just use the working example, but I would like to know WHY the first example doesn't work.

Edit: some additional information

Comment: you `saveApplicationFunction` takes a callback function as the second argument. You need to just pass the function name. what you are doing is calling the function in the second argument. What this does in return is just set the return value of the function as the callback.

Comment: Where is the code for saveApplicationFunction() ?? IN your first example you are passing a reference to a function that happens to then call a function. In your second example you are passing a function that is immediately getting called

Answer (score 0):

The first example you are passing a function that MUST be called on your `saveApplicationFunction` to get the `click` function, the second example you are passing to your `saveApplicationFunction` the return of the `click` function which was called in this scope.

Answer (score 0):

Use an event listener in JS, not the HTML attribute.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button-top-level").addEventListener("click", function() {
    /*Your code here*/
});
```

Comment: I'm using React and I'm not sure that'd be the right way to go, sorry for not mentioning that explicitly(the original post has been edited to mention that now)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your `saveApplicationFunction` takes a `callback` function as the second argument. You need to just pass the **function name**. what you are doing is ***calling the function*** in the second argument. What this does is just set the `return` value of the function as the `callback`.

```js
function handler(value, callback){
  callback(value);
}

const callbackFunc = val => {
  if(val) console.log(val);
  return ()=>console.log('I do Nothing');
}

handler(5, callbackFunc); //Your Second Snippet
handler(5, callbackFunc()); //Your First Snippet
```

Comment: The first example works fine in Chrome for iOS though, why is that?

Comment: Which one works on iOS and which one works on Chrome?

Comment: First one works in chrome on iOS, second works in Safari on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

`In first snippet` you are calling function and passing return value of function as parameter but

`In second snippet` you are just passing `function definition` and I think function `this.props.saveApplicationFunction` do not accept second second parameter to be a callback which it will call.